# Remove wraping paragraph

Tags: php, javascript, regex, wordpress, post

I´like to remove a wrapping `p` by using the inner `span` tag.
This came up by using the WordPress `more` tag on a single post.

My code:

```
<h1>Headline 1</h1>
<p><span id="name-{dyn.PageID}"></span></p>   // Remove the whole <p> by all ID`s
<p>Somne Text</p>
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Comment: How can you remove them? start by _trying_ something, and _show_ your efforts, then remove the regex tag, as that's probably the worst tool for this job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress automatically adds p html tag to your posts, wrapping text, embeds, etc.

You would probably want to try a plugin like this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-p/ which removes this behaviour. There are also other plugins that do the same, but this should do what you need.